# What's the best way to optimize calculating multiple div's width on resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, resize

For this example, on resize, I need to know how to calculate the width of a bunch of divs.

I want to do this in the most absolute performant way possible. Think like an extreme example from just 10 divs to 10,000 divs on a page.

Here's a basic example in jQuery of the issue:

```
$justABunchOfParentDivs = $('.class-matching-500-elements-on-a-page');
$(window).resize(function() {

    $justABunchOfParentDivs.each(function() {
        $(this).attr('data-width', $(this).width());
    });

});
```

**I need a jQuery solution**, but would also like to see non-jQuery solutions that are super fast.

Comment: You're not calculating anything here, what are you trying to achieve? Why is "performance" ab issue here - do you have an actual problem?

Comment: I need to update the data-attribute with the width like the example. If there's 10,000 elements on the page, I want to know if there's a better way with JS. My fear is the solution above will get slow with a large amount of elements

Comment: The best thing that you can do is throttling the event handler. Running that code snippet on each resize  event for 10000 elements can crash the browser. `resize` and `scroll` are 2 wild horses.

Comment: Let's try this again, **why** do you need to update the attribute? Why is that important? The width is changing and you can always read that, why isn't this good enough?

Comment: Fair enough. For **why**: I'm experimenting with a concept for doing "element" media queries. E.g.: https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries. If I use the JS solution with the data-attribute, I can effectively do things like `article[data-width='500px'] { font-size: 16px; } and article[data-width='300px'] { font-size: 12px; }`

Answer (score 3):

To improve performance a little bit you can use `window.requestAnimationFrame` like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    $justABunchOfParentDivs.each(function() {
            $(this).attr('data-width', $(this).width());
    });
  });
});
```

It fires your code only when the browser wants that (better for FPS).
Also if you will do it using standard API it will increase performance as well:

```
$justABunchOfParentDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.class-matching-500-elements-on-a-page');

window.onresize = function() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call($justABunchOfParentDivs, function(element) {
            element.setAttribute('data-width', element.offsetWidth);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Good suggestions. You are missing the `call` function though. Also using `Array.prototype.forEach.call` can be slightly faster than `[].forEach.call`. The `forEach` can also be detached from the prototype in the outer scope and then be called by using the `call` method.

Comment: Mind posting that?

Comment: What do you mean? Did you wrap this code to `$(window).resize(function() {   .....    }):`

Comment: Ah - so you call window.requestAnimationFrame on resize?

Comment: Yes, sure. Let me change my answer

Comment: I like this big time. Tested it in the console with * on every element and it's pretty dang snappy. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Added debouncing to Max's answer. Raw JavaScript:

```
var query = document.querySelectorAll('.class-goes-here'),
    delay = 250,
    timeout = false;

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(query, function(element) {
                  element.setAttribute('data-width', element.offsetWidth);
            });
        });
    }, delay);
});
```